# How to save file temporary?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using dio and path_provider to save pdf from url, I am going to show that pdf to user using open_file. But I have problem with saving path.

Where I can save file temporary, show that file, and after some time or when user will not look at the app delete file? File can be even deleted after 2 days. Time when pdf will be removed is not that important.

It can be even longer time, but sooner or later it must happen. This is in order to not have old pdf's stored on the phone in case of pdf's change on the web

Right now it is my path:

```
               var tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
                String fullPath = "${tempDir.path}/test.pdf";
```

edit: there is also a second option, to check if something is in this place saved, if yes, then remove it and download again, but this place can not be shown to a users, I found "getApplicationDocumentsDirectory", this allows me to save pdf in place where users can not read a pdf.

After that reaserch my question will be, If I download my pdf in a way as you can see above it will stay in that place and will never be moved? Now I need to only creade a methode that will see if my pdf is there end will remove it? How to extract name of my pdf I will need that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have selected the right path if you just needed to delete the file for the space on device because when you use the getTemporaryDirectory() the system will automatically delete files in this directory as disk space is needed elsewhere on the device. The system will always delete older files first, based on the lastModifiedTime.

But if you want to check if the file changed or not you can send in the response of the file a flag that contains the last updated date and this value can be the file name prefix, so when ever you open the app you can check if the date has changed you will delete the old one manually and store the new one.

If you follow this solution it will be no need to use getTemporaryDirectory() you have to use the getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()